# How to create a new file based on results from multiple files and keep the filenames as first column?

Tags: bash, for, bioinformatics

I wanted to extract specific lines from multiple `bam` (a binary file format) files. I can select the lines from a single `bam` file using this command:

```
samtools view -c TCGA-BH-A0BW-11A.sorted.bam "5:13744354-13744380"
550
```

I have a directory with 100 `bam` files like below:

```
TCGA-AC-A2FB-11A.sorted.bam
TCGA-AC-A2FF-11A.sorted.bam
TCGA-AC-A2FM-11B.sorted.bam
TCGA-AC-A2QH-01A.sorted.bam
TCGA-AC-A2QJ-01A.sorted.bam
TCGA-BH-A0BW-11A.sorted.bam
TCGA-BH-A0BW-01A.sorted.bam
TCGA-CH-A0BW-11A.sorted.bam
```

How do I apply the command to multiple `bam` files and save the output in a single file with the first column as the file name without the extension and the second column being the result of the `samtools` command on this file?

For example: It should somehow look like this

```
TCGA-BH-A0BW-11A     550
TCGA-BH-A0BW-01A     220
TCGA-CH-A0BW-11A     100
```

I am working on a Linux system.

Comment: Remember that people here are not bioinformaticians, so don't expect them to know what reads are or what bam files are. When asking here, make sure that someone with no knowledge of bioinformatics has enough information to answer the question (as I did with my edit). By the way, you might be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `bash`, you can iterate over all files with the appropriate extension, and process them as follows:

```
for file in *.sorted.bam
do
    key="${file%.sorted.bam}"
    value="$(samtools view -c "$file" "5:13744354-13744380")"
    echo "$key $value"
done > output.txt
```

In the loop, we

- generate the file key by removing `.sorted.bam` from the end of the filename (and store it in a shell variable `key`)
- perform the processing as shown in your single-file example and store the output in a shell variable `value`
- print both key and value

and redirect the overall output of the loop to a file `output.txt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and well informative reply.